# pip install pysall - failed to build rvlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysal

I want to install the package pysal. I have tried using 'pip install pysal', and I already have all of its dependencies installed. This is the error I get:

`python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully. exit code: 1`

then

`note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for rvlib Running setup.py clean for rvlib Failed to build rvlib ERROR: Could not build wheels for rvlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I would be very appreciative of any help.

Comment: Have you checked their issues? https://github.com/pysal/pysal/issues/1267

Comment: I have done so. The package installed, but does not work. If I try: import pysal.lib.weights, I get an error stating it cannot find the module 'Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\llvmlite.dll'

Answer (score 0):

Even I have had the same issues for a while. I found that there are certain problems with installation of **PySAL** dependencies. And problem was with construction **rvlib** within local systems via **PyPI or pip**. Therefore, Step1 would be - create a seperate environment for PySAL in Conda and run the following lines.

```
pip install segregation==2.0.0
pip install pysal==2.5.0
```

For more information check https://github.com/pysal/pysal/issues/1267

The above solution should work. However, if you want to install using `pip install pysal`, try using `conda install rvlib` and check https://github.com/QuantEcon/rvlib/issues/29 to know more.

Moreover, I did not test with installation of rvlib as the former method sufficiently well on Windows.